# exim4 happen: Too many "Received" headers - suspected mail loop

Tags: exim, exim4, mailman

When I use Mailman and ExIM4 to set up a mailing list server, I send information to the mailing list using my personal mailbox, and the message "Action: failed, Final-Recipient: rfc822;  dev@tomtoworld.xyz  Status: 5.0.0" is returned. The log output is as follows:

```
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Ht-G3 <= 353712217@qq.com H=(71b59c6d89cc) [43.155.80.72] P=esmtp S=19481 id=tencent_42C7156C70D41B29B12B9B720262AA270908@qq.com T="test" from <353712217@qq.
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Hp-F0 => dev@tomtoworld.xyz F=<353712217@qq.com> P=<353712217@qq.com> R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains T=remote_smtp H=tomtoworld.xyz [43.155.80.72] C="250 OK id
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Hp-F0 Completed
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Hx-HB <= 353712217@qq.com H=(71b59c6d89cc) [43.155.80.72] P=esmtp S=20101 id=tencent_42C7156C70D41B29B12B9B720262AA270908@qq.com T="test" from <353712217@qq.
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Ht-G3 => dev@tomtoworld.xyz F=<353712217@qq.com> P=<353712217@qq.com> R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains T=remote_smtp H=tomtoworld.xyz [43.155.80.72] C="250 OK id
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Ht-G3 Completed
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I1-IH <= 353712217@qq.com H=(71b59c6d89cc) [43.155.80.72] P=esmtp S=20721 id=tencent_42C7156C70D41B29B12B9B720262AA270908@qq.com T="test" from <353712217@qq.
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Hx-HB => dev@tomtoworld.xyz F=<353712217@qq.com> P=<353712217@qq.com> R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains T=remote_smtp H=tomtoworld.xyz [43.155.80.72] C="250 OK id
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000Hx-HB Completed
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I5-JM <= 353712217@qq.com H=(71b59c6d89cc) [43.155.80.72] P=esmtp S=21341 id=tencent_42C7156C70D41B29B12B9B720262AA270908@qq.com T="test" from <353712217@qq.
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I1-IH => dev@tomtoworld.xyz F=<353712217@qq.com> P=<353712217@qq.com> R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains T=remote_smtp H=tomtoworld.xyz [43.155.80.72] C="250 OK id
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I1-IH Completed
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I5-JM ** dev@tomtoworld.xyz F=<353712217@qq.com>: Too many "Received" headers - suspected mail loop
2022-05-04 13:19:09 1nmEuL-0000I8-KE <= <> R=1nmEuL-0000I5-JM U=Debian-exim P=local S=22506 T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" from <>
```

I have set and checked through DKIM, SPF, DMARC. But the problem remains.
Have any idea to solve this question?